# URL validate with regular expression and add "http://" when it's missing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a function to validate url regular expression,
and add "http://" if it's missing at the same time.
I am quite new to Javascript and coding, and most part of the below code
is what I have followed a Youtube tutorial.

But I wanted to add a function to prepend "http://" when it's missing,
since with the current regex, both "www.google.com" and "http://www.google.com"
is valid. The problem with this is when I actually click to visit the website,
the ones saved without "http://" at start, doesn't go to the site.

```
function validateForm(siteName, siteUrl) {
    if(!siteName || !siteUrl) {
        alert('Please fill in the form');
        return false;
    }


    var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    var result = siteUrl.search(new RegExp(/^http:\/\//i));

    if(!siteUrl.match(regex)) {
        alert('Please use a valid URL');
        return false;
    }
    else if(siteUrl.match(regex) && !result) {
        siteUrl = "http://" + siteUrl
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** string method to determine if `http://` is at the beginning of the string. However, you may run into problems prepending `http://` if the URL requires `https://`.

```
else if(siteUrl.match(regex) && !result) {

    // Check to see if the string starts with "http://"
    // indexOf() returns the index position of the supplied
    // string argument within the string. 
    if(siteUrl.indexOf("http://") !== 0){
       siteUrl = "http://" + siteUrl
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also (as @m_callens points out in the comments below), your `siteUrl` variable is a function argument, so you won't be able to access it from outside of the function. Instead you should not pass it into the function at all and just have it declared in a higher scope:

```
var siteUrl = // Code that initializes the variable

function validateForm(siteName) {
    if(!siteName || !siteUrl) {
        alert('Please fill in the form');
        return false;
    }


    var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
    var regex = new RegExp(expression);
    var result = siteUrl.search(new RegExp(/^http:\/\//i));

    if(!siteUrl.match(regex)) {
        alert('Please use a valid URL');
        return false;
    }
    else if(siteUrl.match(regex) && !result) {
        // Check to see if the string starts with "http://"
        // indexOf() returns the index position of the supplied
        // string argument within the string. 
        if(siteUrl.indexOf("http://") !== 0){
           siteUrl = "http://" + siteUrl
        }
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the issue that he's attempting to change a variable, `siteUrl`, for the outside scope when it is only local to the function

Comment: That's a good point (but, wasn't was the question was asking). I'll update my answer to address it.

Comment: also, the index of a non-existing substring is -1, however, you're prepending if the index is equal to 0.

Comment: Too early for me still. Need coffee!

Comment: Actually, I'm preoccupied by an issue with Stack Overflow itself that I'm experiencing right now. Their banner is gone and I'm trying to see why.

Comment: @m_callens OK. Now I think I know what the problem is. I was just totally ignoring the scope of variable, aren't I? Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @tthustla yeah, while a bit over-engineered, I didn't see anything inherently wrong with your code other than expected a global change for a local variable.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you for your answer! and as it has been mentioned in the comments above, maybe I should try to change the value of siteUrl outside the function?

Comment: Changing it inside the function is perfectly fine as long as the declaration of the variable is in a higher scope than the function. If you look at my example you'll see that I moved the declaration outside of the function and remove the parameter.

Comment: You really don't need the function to be returning true or false. You just need it to correct the URL, which it does. So just make sure you call the function before you use the URL.